# Magento Connect shutting down on Sept 15, will Magento Connect Manager work?

Tags: magento-1.9

I've noticed that Magento Connect (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/) is moving to Magento Marketplace (https://marketplace.magento.com/).

**Are we still will be able to Update already installed extensions via Magento Connect Manager if magentoconnect.com website will be shut down after Sept 15 ?**

Comment: Its down but where I will get my company extension which we developed for Magento 1 and was available on Magento Connect? Do we need to upload on marketplace extension?

Comment: @YogeshTrivedi Yes you must send your Extenson to Marketplace for quality check before it will be available for others to download.